# Send picture to API through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to call this [web service](https://ocr.a9t9.com/api/Parse/Image) to recognize the text in a picture (OCR), but the call always fails with this error when using the example provided in jQuery

> System.InvalidOperationException: No file uploaded or URL provided ↵
>   bei OCRReaderMVCWeb.Controllers.OCRAPIController.Parse() in
>   d:\3bitbucket\1ocr.aaaa.com\OCRReaderMVCWeb\Controllers\OCRAPIController.cs:Zeile
>   243.

Documentation: https://ocr.a9t9.com/OCRAPI
The API only accepts four parameters:

- apiKey: "helloworld" (free license)
- file: upload jpg image
- url: location of a remote image
- language: "eng" English by defualt

I've tried the API with curl commands and works fine as well as using the url commented in the code snippet below. I know you can't submit documents without an iframe with jQuery so the example provided is not correct.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Prepare form data
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", "@5.jpg");
        //formData.append("url", "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02007/Plate-1_2007614b.jpg"); //url of remote image
        formData.append("language", "eng");
        formData.append("apikey", "helloworld");
  
        //Send OCR Parsing request asynchronously
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://ocr.a9t9.com/api/Parse/Image",
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'Post',
            success: function (ocrParsedResult) {
                //Get the parsed results, exit code and error message and details
                var parsedResults = ocrParsedResult["ParsedResults"];
                var ocrExitCode = ocrParsedResult["OCRExitCode"];
                var isErroredOnProcessing = ocrParsedResult["IsErroredOnProcessing"];
                var errorMessage = ocrParsedResult["ErrorMessage"];
                var errorDetails = ocrParsedResult["ErrorDetails"];
                
                //If we have got parsed results, then loop over the results to do something
                console.log("success? " );
                if (parsedResults != null) {
                    
                    //Uncomment these lines if parsing multiple results
                    $.each(parsedResults, function (index, value) {
                        var exitCode = value["FileParseExitCode"];
                        var parsedText = value["ParsedText"];
                        var errorMessage = value["ParsedTextFileName"];
                        var errorDetails = value["ErrorDetails"];
                        console.log("text: " + parsedText);
                        var pageText = '';
                        switch (+exitCode) {
                            case 1:
                                pageText = parsedText;
                                break;
                            case 0:
                            case -10:
                            case -20:
                            case -30:
                            case -99:
                            default:
                                pageText += "Error: " + errorMessage;
                                break;
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: a `fileName` is not a `file` object ... so the error is correct, there is no file

Comment: @charlietfl Oh fine I understand what you meant. Get led astray at first sight

Comment: Solutions belong in an answer, not in the question. Please remove the solution and put it in an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
            function uploadPicture()
            {
                //Prepare form data
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", $("#inputFileToLoad")[0].files[0]);
                //formData.append("url", "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02007/Plate-1_2007614b.jpg"); //url of remote image
                formData.append("language", "eng");
                formData.append("apikey", "helloworld");
                callService(formData);                     
            }
            
            function callService(formData)
            {
                //Send OCR Parsing request asynchronously
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "https://ocr.a9t9.com/api/Parse/Image",
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (ocrParsedResult) {
                        //Get the parsed results, exit code and error message and details
                        console.log("Success!");
                        var parsedResults = ocrParsedResult["ParsedResults"];
                        var ocrExitCode = ocrParsedResult["OCRExitCode"];
                        var isErroredOnProcessing = ocrParsedResult["IsErroredOnProcessing"];
                        var errorMessage = ocrParsedResult["ErrorMessage"];
                        var errorDetails = ocrParsedResult["ErrorDetails"];
                        //If we have got parsed results, then loop over the results to do something
                        if (parsedResults != null) {
                            //Uncomment these lines if parsing multiple results
                            $.each(parsedResults, function (index, value) {
                                var exitCode = value["FileParseExitCode"];
                                var parsedText = value["ParsedText"];
                                var errorMessage = value["ParsedTextFileName"];
                                var errorDetails = value["ErrorDetails"];
                                
                                console.log("OCR: " + parsedText);
                                $("#text").html( parsedText);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });   
            }            
</script>
```

```html
  <p>Select a File to Load:</p>
    <input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="loadImageFileAsURL();" />
    <p>File Contents as DataURL:</p>
    <textarea id="textAreaFileContents" style="width:640;height:240"></textarea>
    <p>OCR</p>
    <input type="submit" onclick="uploadPicture();" value="OCR" />
    <div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl pointed out,

```
formData.append("file", "@5.jpg");
```

is not a file, just a file name.

The docs says that the file must be a `Multipart encoded image file with filename` so I guess you'll have to encode your image in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) before sending it through the API.
Get started [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/D%C3%A9coder_encoder_en_base64).

It worked though `cURL` because

```
curl --form "file=@5.jpg" [...]
```

was actually pointing to the real image, but JS will just interpret this as a string.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on the real solution so I'll update my question soon.

Comment: You were in the right track when saying the problem was related with the picture. Using my approach above there is no need to encode the image to Base64, you just need to pass the value into the function but I left the serialization bit if someone needed.